# How do I group ICommands so that if one is executing the others can't?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

If I bind an ICommand to a control in WPF it is enabled/disaled based on the CanExecute state of the command. I am aware that disabling execution of multiple commands can be accomplished using one boolean field in all of the CanExcecute implementations of ICommand I want to "group". My question is, should I do this like that or do it in XAML in some way? Is there any "standard" way to do it? Any .NET class to manage it?

Comment: There is no built-in class in .NET for that. Check this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25808/Aggregating-WPF-Commands-with-CommandGroup) it explains aggregating the commands into container. You'll probably need something like that

Comment: You can extend you own `ICommand` implementation as much as you need. E.g. you can automate disabling multiple commands by obtaining references of all of them and rising `CanExecuteChanged` for each somehow.

Comment: Since you can't group ICommands (each command has its own 'CanExecute()') you have to implement this logic by yourself. Having a flag dedicated to each group and added to the individual 'CanExecute()' as you suggested would work. But it would be cleaner to create a  'CanGroupExecute()' method that is invoked before each individual condition check (e.g.  'CanGroupExecute()' &&  'CanExecute()'). This way the Implementation of the primary condition if a group of commands can execute is encapsulated and doesn't polute all individual  'CanExecute()' members.

Comment: CanGroupExecute() is a nice idea but no external code knows about methods outside of ICommand so for example WPF won't automatically disable controls (like buttons etc.) based on "can execute" status of a bound command.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such class included in the .NET Framework but you could take a look at how the [CompositeCommand](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Commands/CompositeCommand.cs) class is implemented in Prism.

From the [docs](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/composite-commands.html):

> It maintains a list of child commands (`DelegateCommand` instances). The `Execute` method of the `CompositeCommand` class simply calls the `Execute` method on each of the child commands in turn. The `CanExecute` method similarly calls the `CanExecute` method of each child command, but if any of the child commands cannot be executed, the `CanExecute` method will return `false`. In other words, by default, a `CompositeCommand` can only be executed when all the child commands can be executed.

You associate child commands using the `RegisterCommand` method of the `CompositeCommand` class:

```
public DelegateCommand UpdateCommand { get; private set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Update);
    ApplicationCommands.SaveCommand.RegisterCommand(UpdateCommand);
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I need exclusive execution of one command from a "group". So I need to set ^can execute^ for all other commands to false and raise their CanExecuteChanged. Then I would have to allow the execution again. It seems that simple boolean flag is the way to go here. Tried to tackle this in some nicer way but it only creates more problems.

Comment: So what is your current issue then? There is no "standard" way of doing this.

Comment: mm8 Thanks. I understand. There is no issue. I just have to do it with boolean flags. Messy.

Comment: mm8 There are no answers for my question. Your answer is great but to a different question ;)

Comment: @ed22: The answers to your questions, *Is there any "standard" way to do it?* and  *Any .NET class to manage it?*, is obviously no.

Comment: @ed22: What's wrong with *There is no such class included in the .NET Framework...*?

Comment: Yes, that part is ok but the CompositeCommand is completely not the answer. I don't want anyone having that problem looking into that.

Comment: How did you finally solve this issue, @ed22?

Comment: @thomasgalliker as far as I remember I just made it work with boolean flags. Haven't found any standard way.

Comment: We put some time into this issue. Have a look at my answer and the link to the Prism issue I created.

Answer (score 1):

I proposed a solution with a new construct (`CommandGroup` class) which synchronizes an execution flag in a thread-safe way. Multiple commands are created in a CommandGroup. When one command is executed, a flag is set. When another command attempts to execute, it first checks the flag: If another command of the same group is already running, the later command will not start to execute.

`Interlocked.CompareExchange` is used to check if a command is currently executing and to toggle the execution flag (`_currentState`) in one atomic operation. As soon as the execution is finished, the `_currentState` is reverted, again, using a thread-safe operation (`Interlocked.Exchange`).

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _currentState, Running, NotRunning) == NotRunning)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"CommandGroup: Command execution started");

    try
    {
        await execute(p);
    }
    finally
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"CommandGroup: Command execution finished");
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _currentState, NotRunning);
    }
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"CommandGroup: Command execution skipped");
}
```

More explanation and the full source code can be found here:
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2890

**Your comments are highly welcome.** Did you experience this problem too? How did you solve it?

Comment: This is nice. Prism probably won't include this as a too specific case scenario but your answer would very useful for my specific case (a long time ago :)